# Which skill would be more useful for a data scientist?

Tags: mlops

1. DevOps
2. Full Stack Development.

Comment: You need to provide more context; this is too broad of a question. What background do you have? What goals do you have for your career?

Comment: @StefanPopov I am currently applying for data science positions, so i need to boost my skills. I am familiar with both fields, Devops and web development.

Comment: Why apply to data science positions if you lack the training? (This isn’t sarcasm; your response will be enlightening.)

Comment: @Dave I know enough to get a data science job. I did an internship and I am working as a freelancer. I just want to some skills to basket to land a good position.

Answer (score 2):

From my personal experience, I would say DevOps. DevOps skills help you deploy your models into production more efficiently and easily. Moreover, in some cases DevOps teaches you how to manipulate and wrangle data, which is essential knowledge for every data scientist. Full stack development, on the other hand, includes front-end which is something that I almost never bump into and also server programming, which honestly is something I never had to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already working, or have knowledge of the two areas you mentioned; I'd agree with what @Nemo_the_scientist says, i.e., `DevOps > Full Stack Development` for data science; though I feel bit eerie saying something like that, because the three areas are overlapping, and it is not right to say knowledge of the one is better than the other.

In my work (as a data scientist / ML engineer) I have dealt more with dev ops works (dealing with CI/CD pipelines, model deployment, monitoring, retraining, etc.) than with any front/back end development.

Logically, you can view an ML model as an artifact similar to a complete  business application, and you need to continuously integrate it with other systems, keep it up-to-date by retraining, monitoring its performance (both in terms of performance on the business, and in terms of software - prediction latency, model size, memory requirements, etc.). This sounds more like the dev ops, rather then full-stack programming. On the other hand, I'd think that full-stack programmers are better equipped to work with databases and this would help you greatly in data science role.

To wrap up: you'll need some skills from both fields (maybe bit more from dev ops). Have a look at what skills some popular online courses are offering, or what skills job ads at big and middle sized companies are requesting.